# Sorting QComboBox delete data in UserRole

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with custom data in a QCombo Box and here is a minimal example, just an empty project with a QComboBox named combobox in the ui.
Here is the c'tor code:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

//Add the sort proxy
QSortFilterProxyModel* proxy = new QSortFilterProxyModel(ui->comboBox);
proxy->setSourceModel(ui->comboBox->model());
ui->comboBox->model()->setParent(proxy);
ui->comboBox->setModel(proxy);

//First strange thing is
//Here the first addItem triggers the current index changed signal
//In the second run, every addItem trigger the signal


qDebug() << "Initializing";
for( size_t i=1; i<1e10; i*=10 )
    ui->comboBox->addItem( "item",  i );

qDebug() << "Sorting";
proxy->sort(0);
proxy->sort(0);

qDebug() << "Selecting";
ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);


//Here everything is fine


for( int i=0; i<ui->comboBox->count(); ++i )
    qDebug() << ui->comboBox->itemData(i).value<size_t>();



//Clear the box and do the same again!

ui->comboBox->clear();

//Now every addItem triggers the current changed event
qDebug() << "Initializing";
for( size_t i=1; i<1e10; i*=10 )
    ui->comboBox->addItem( "item",  i );

qDebug() << "Sorting";
proxy->sort(0);

qDebug() << "Selecting";
ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);


//Here all itemData values are 0!!!


for( int i=0; i<ui->comboBox->count(); ++i )
    qDebug() << ui->comboBox->itemData(i).value<size_t>();
```

And here is the slot

```
void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    qDebug() << "Current changed to " << index;
    qDebug() << "UserRole is " << ui->comboBox->itemData(index);
}
```

The second time add the items calls the current index changed event every time, the first time just on the first addItem.

In the second run, after sort, all user data is 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This (http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/3741-How-to-sort-a-QComboBox-in-Qt4) post suggest that its a bug. Its almost 10 years old i know but im getting the same error. If you remove the first sort(0) the data doesn't disappear.
Maybe you could make a custom insert function so the items insert in the correct order. Just like

```
ui->comboBox->setInsertPolicy(QComboBox::InsertAlphabetically);
```

but with the lessThan behaviour.